# video is not displayed on smartphone using video tag html5

Tags: html, video, smartphone

i'm making a landingpage website. I use a video to display, but the problem is that the video is not shown on my phone when I go to the website. 
This is the code I used to implement the video

```
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
    <source src="video/bgVid7.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: It is possibly an issue with the video format - if you provide a link to the video this can be checked.

Comment: Videos don't autoplay on mobile. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro. Yes that could be it, Do you know a way to do it anyway?